# Double registration form on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, civievent

I got something quite strange and do not how to solve it.
In my Wordpress 5.6.1 /CiviCRM 5.34 integration (my first WP integration but have am also working with D7/Civi for 8+ years)
I get a double registration screen. It shows in the main area AND in the footer.

I am using the native url and not the shortcode.
https://www.mydomain.nl/civicrm/event/register/?reset=1&id=12

UPDATE: it is only when I use a selected page as a footer in my enfold theme

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use JetPack or another widget visibility plugin to prevent showing the page in the footer when you're on the CiviCRM Base Page.

EDIT: The following code prevents CiviCRM from overriding the content a second time:

```
add_action( 'civicrm_basepage_parsed', 'my_civicrm_disable_content_filter' );

function my_civicrm_disable_content_filter() {
    // Once the CiviCRM filter has run, remove it.
    add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_civicrm_remove_content_filter', 100 );
}

function my_civicrm_remove_content_filter( $content ) {
    static $done;
    if ( ! isset( $done ) ) {
        remove_filter( 'the_content', [ civi_wp()->basepage, 'basepage_render' ] );
        $done = true;
    }
    return $content;
}
```

This should mean that your second page renders as expected.

Comment: @richard-van-oosterhout Add the code above in your `functions.php` file (maybe replacing `my_` with your child theme's custom prefix) and your issue should go away on the base page. If you use Shortcodes, I'll update with further code to fix that.

Comment: Also, you may want to look at the PR I've just opened for a simpler solution: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-wordpress/pull/240