# CiviCRM content duplicated in multiple WP theme regions

Tags: wordpress

I have a clean install of 5.70.1 on WP.  After creating a test contribution page, I noticed that CiviCRM content appears repeatedly on the page in what appears to be different content regions of the WP theme.

I've not seen this before and not sure where to dig in.

Contribution Page: http://t12.4f6.mywebsitetransfer.com/civicrm/contribute/transact/?reset=1&id=1

Profile Create: http://t12.4f6.mywebsitetransfer.com/civicrm/profile/create/?gid=1&reset=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/38854/double-registration-form-on-wordpress

Comment: Looks to me as though you have two "Main Loops" going on. CiviCRM will render its content twice in such circumstances. Have a look at the linked question